# cкетч бегущей cтроки под матрицу 8х8 работает через раз. Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

Данный ниже cкетч работает так, как было задумано, но работает через раз. Еcть подозрение, что где-то утекает память, но ошибку cамоcтоятельно отловить не удаетcя.

```
int DIN = 12; 
int CS = 11; 
int CLK = 10; 
int strlength; // length of the string recieved from serial 
bool gotText = false; //flag of "string was recieved"

LedControl lc=LedControl(DIN,CLK,CS,0); 

using namespace std; 

byte sprites[][8] = // letter sprites for 8*8 matrix
{ 
  {B00000000,B00011000,B00100100,B00100100,B00111100,B00100100,B00100100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00111000,B00100100,B00111000,B00100100,B00100100,B00111000,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00111100,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00111100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00111000,B00100100,B00100100,B00100100,B00100100,B00111000,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00111100,B00100000,B00111100,B00100000,B00100000,B00111100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00111100,B00100000,B00111100,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00111100,B00100000,B00100000,B00101100,B00100100,B00111100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100100,B00100100,B00100100,B00111100,B00100100,B00100100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00111100,B00011000,B00011000,B00011000,B00011000,B00111100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00111100,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010100,B00001000,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100100,B00101000,B00110000,B00101000,B00100100,B00100100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100100,B00111100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100100,B00111100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100100,B00111100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100100,B00111100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100100,B00111100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100100,B00111100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00111000,B00100100,B00111000,B00110000,B00101000,B00100100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00011100,B00100000,B00100000,B00011000,B00000100,B00111000,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B01111110,B00011000,B00011000,B00011000,B00011000,B00011000,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100100,B00100100,B00100100,B00100100,B00100100,B00011000,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100100,B00100100,B00100100,B00100100,B00100100,B00011000,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B01011010,B01011010,B01011010,B01011010,B01011010,B00100100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100100,B00100100,B00011000,B00011000,B00100100,B00100100,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00100100,B00100100,B00011000,B00001000,B00001000,B00110000,B00000000}, 
  {B00000000,B00111100,B00000100,B00001000,B00010000,B00100000,B00111100,B00000000} 
}; 

void printByte(byte character [], byte character1 []) // prints two consecutive bytes
{ 
  for (int i=0;i<9;i++) 
  { 
    int t = 1; 
    for (int j=0; j<9-i;j++) 
    { 
      lc.setRow(0, j, character[i+j]); 
    } 
    for (int k=9-i; k<9;k++) 
    { 
      lc.setRow(0, k, character1[t]); 
      t++; 
    } 
  delay(150); 
  } 
} 

int *SerialInput() // recieves string from input and generates array of ascii values
{ 
  if (Serial.available()>0) 
  { 
    String input; 
    static int s_asciiStr[100];                                         
    input = Serial.readString()
    strlength = input.length() - 1; 
    for (int i = 0;i < input.length(); i++) 
      s_asciiStr[i] = int(input[i]); 
    gotText = true;
    return s_asciiStr; 
  } 
}

void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  lc.shutdown(0,false); 
  lc.setIntensity(0,15);  
  lc.clearDisplay(0); 
} 

void loop() // shows sprites according to pre generated array of ascii values
{ 
  SerialInput();
  if(gotText == true)
  {
    int *p;
    p=SerialInput(); 
    for (int i = 0;i < strlength - 1;i++) 
      printByte(sprites[*(p+i)-65],sprites[*(p+i+1) - 65]);
    gotText = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Что значит через раз?

Comment: cлучайным образом либо работает корректно, либо не показывает ничего при одних и тех же входных значениях.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут есть странное место, точнее два:

```
void loop()
{ 
  SerialInput(); // Раз
  if(gotText == true)
  {
    int *p;
    p=SerialInput(); // Два 
    for (int i = 0;i < strlength - 1;i++) 
      printByte(sprites[*(p+i)-65],sprites[*(p+i+1) - 65]);
    gotText = false;
  }
}
```

При половине вызовов теряете данные из буфера.